unable to update ubuntu24.04 : Conflicting values set for option :: The list of sources could not be read
when run sudo apt-get update it gives error of
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By 
regarding source https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/ stable: 
/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.

earlier I was getting long error and following one of solution I have deleted that faulty package update
sudo rm /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg 


it says
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/keyrings/packages-microsoft.gpg': No such file or directory

how to fix this?
also the software & update package window not getting opened and there is error message on top right of desktop as below

Update
run
> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list

and then
> sudo apt-get-update

it runs but ends with below warning.
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) 
entry for 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code'


now able to open software & update package window and uncheck vs code from software updates but does this work?


By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals to see your text. It's unscrollable, so wr can'tsee the rest of the nessage. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the {} formatting tool.

Where did I post picture of text? Yes the text overflow issue is there and wil fix it

@waltinator the {} formatting will produce a box that allows side scrolling on overflow. It's not the best UI in the world as it shows no indication of it with scrollbars or similar, but it's still text and not a picture.

I have mentioned similar question in question and that does not worked at all. please make habit of reading full context before raining for close.

sudo rm /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg gives rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/keyrings/packages-microsoft.gpg': No such file or directory. How is this possible? See the difference in the filename!

yup. it was . not -
